# setting grid view using customgridadapter

Tags: android, android-gridview

It's not displaying anything in the grid. Is there anything wrong? Please suggest a solution.

My JSON array is stored in a list called `seat_list`. I want to place some images in the grid based on the values in this array, but it displays nothing.

JSON parsing:

```
private void json_parser(JSONArray jarray) {
    try {

        seat_list = new ArrayList<Seat_Availabe>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);



              String clmn = object.getString("row");



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), clmn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            column = Integer.parseInt("clmn");

            if(j <= column)
            {
                j = column;
            }


            seat_list.add(new Seat_Availabe(object.getString("available"), object.getString("baseFare"), object.getString("column"), object.getString("fare"), object.getString("ladiesSeat"), object.getString("length"), object.getString("name"), object.getString("operatorServiceChargeAbsolute"), object.getString("operatorServiceChargePercent"), object.getString("row"), object.getString("serviceTaxAbsolute"), object.getString("serviceTaxPercentage"), object.getString("width"), object.getString("zIndex")));

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), j, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        gridView.setNumColumns(j+1);
        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.seatrow_grid, seat_list);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        //Stuff element in blank space of array



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("@json_parser", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my custom adapter, `CustomGridViewAdapter`:

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Seat_Availabe>{
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
List<Seat_Availabe> data = new ArrayList<Seat_Availabe>();

public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,        List<Seat_Availabe> data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;


    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        Seat_Availabe seat = data.get(position);
        ImageView imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);


        if (seat.getAvailable().toString().equals("true") && seat.getLadiesSeat().toString().equals("false")) {

           imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);

        }
        else if(seat.getAvailable().toString().equals("False"))
        {

            imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray);
        }
        else if(seat.getAvailable().toString().equals("true") && seat.getLadiesSeat().toString().equals("true")){

            imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.pink);
        }
        else{

            imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
        }
    }

    return row;
 }


}
```

Comment: What about seat_list. Are you sure, its not empty?

Comment: did you check the seat_list ?

Comment: it contains all values

Comment: May be you are missing the 'getCount()' method in your ArrayAdapter class... and if so override getCount() and return data.size().

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in getView(...)

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Seat_Availabe>{
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
List<Seat_Availabe> data = new ArrayList<Seat_Availabe>();

public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,        List<Seat_Availabe> data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;


    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }

        Seat_Availabe seat = data.get(position);
        ImageView imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);


        if (seat.getAvailable().toString().equals("true") && seat.getLadiesSeat().toString().equals("false")) {

           imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);

        }
        else if(seat.getAvailable().toString().equals("False"))
        {

            imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray);
        }
        else if(seat.getAvailable().toString().equals("true") && seat.getLadiesSeat().toString().equals("true")){

            imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.pink);
        }
        else{

            imageItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
        }


    return row;
}
```

Comment: What's the output? Have you tried overriding getCount(...) ?